# How do I update ranges to be non-overlapping?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a table `foo` with columns `id` (not unique), `start_date`, and `end_date`. I want, for all the rows with a certain `id`, that no [`start_date`, `end_date`) range overlaps. I want to do this by changing the `end_date` of the offending rows.

I have

```
update foo old
set end_date = new.start_date
from foo new
where old.start_date < new.start_date and old.end_date > new.start_date
and old.id = new.id and new.id = 8675309;
```

However, this won't work if `old` overlaps multiple other records. My best attempt is

```
update foo old
set end_date = (select coalesce(min(new.start_date), old.end_date)
    from foo new
    where old.start_date < new.start_date and old.end_date > new.start_date
    and new.id = old.id)
where old.id = 8675309;
```

This works, but it updates every row unnecessarily, and feels like a hack. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This supposes `start_date` is unique within an `id`

```
update foo
set end_date = s.lsd
from (
    select
        id, start_date,
        lead (start_date, 1, end_date) over (
            partition by id order by start_date
        ) as lsd
    from foo
) s
where
    foo.id = s.id and
    foo.start_date = s.start_date and
    foo.end_date > s.lsd
```